# Refused to execute script from 'bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack, webpack-dev-server, django-webpack-loader

I have an application with CRA with frontend and django backend. I use `react-app-rewired` to override webpack configuration on frontend so that to save output from webpack-dev-server for django to use.

But I hit the issue as shown in below screenshot.
[image]

Below is my override-config.js which used to override out-of-box CRA webpack config
[image]

**Weird thing** is that there is no such issue for frontend product build(run `yarn build` and then open `localhost:8000` in browser and I can get frontend correctly). Above `Refuse to execute ...` issue only happen when I run `yarn start` for development mode.

Here is my package.json
[image]

And django frontend.html
[image]

Relative part in django settings.py
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this only happend in debug mode which is `DEBUG = True` in Django settings.py? Maybe you would try add `assets` to urlpatterns

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static("/assets/",
                          document_root=settings.FRONTEND_PRODUCTION_DIR)
```

reference the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) here.

Comment: Thanks. Django DEBUG is always True for both frontend production and development modes. Adding urlpatterns not fix this issue.